# Connecting Game Objects to a pane from a spawner in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a pane with one cube on it with a spawner which will spawn cubes out when the game is played. The pane can be rotated and the cubes should stick to it and move forward.
The part i am stuck on is making the cubes that come from the spawner to stick.

I managed to make the original cube stick using

```
Object1.transform.parent = Object2.transform;
```

I also managed to make the spawner stick to the pane using the same method.

However when i use this the first cube will stick fine and the cubes from the spawner are not showing up. From what i have researched it could be a scaling issue. Also the spawned cubes do appear under the cube as "Cube(clone)" but their scale is diffrent to the original cube. I have also noticed the scale of the original Cube changes when i press play. It goes from - (10,10,10) to float numbers.

A solution i tried was to set the scale but when i done this the objects did not stick on to the pane at all.

However they did spawn normally.Using this method.

```
 void Update () {
     Vector3 scale = new Vector3(10, 10, 10);
     Object1.transform.localScale = scale;
     Object1.transform.parent = Object2.transform;
}
```

If anyone has any ideas it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you aware you can set the parent of an object? In your case it sounds like you'd want to parent your spawned cubes to the "pane"? One an object is the child of another object, any transforms (position, rotation or scale) will be applied to the children.

Comment: Yes, i have put the cube as the child of the plane and this does work for the original cube and the rotation is the same between them. However when i do this the spawner stops working, the cubes that its meant to spawn next are in weird sizes. The numbers that are shown on the scale are the same but visually they are completely different to the original cube. I have messed around with the scale but i  feel like when i put the cube as the child the spawned objects after are using another scale when its linked with the plane.

Comment: Uh huh, if I understand correctly, it might be a case that AFTER you've parented the newly instantiated object to the plane, you readjust the `cube.transform.localPosition`, `cube.transform.localRotation` and `cube.transform.localScale`. Parenting an object doesn't modify the worldspace transform values, but the local transform values will look way off.

Comment: @Milan Egon Votrubec Thank you Very much. That was the case i messed around with setting the localPosition and Rotation after and before i made the cube a child and it worked.

Comment: I'll pop that in as the answer then. Good to hear you've got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In situations like this, it's quite often best to parent an object first, then deal with the local transformations. Local transformations such as `transform.localPosition`, `transform.localRotation` and `transform.localScale` deal with the object's local values in relation to the parent.

There's a paragraph at the end of [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html) that describes it well:

> Note that the parent transform's world rotation and scale are applied
>   to the local position when calculating the world position. This means
>   that while 1 unit in Transform.position is always 1 unit, 1 unit in
>   Transform.localPosition will get scaled by the scale of all ancestors.